# Windows does not detect monitor turning off

Tags: windows-10, amd-radeon, displayport

I have two monitors identified as LG Ultragear 27GL850. A bit different model in fact, but basically the same. Both connected via DP. With DP connection it is possible that when you're turning a monitor on/off, Windows (10) detects it and changes screen configuration accordingly. And that was exactly so with my older monitors.

However, now with the new model I've mentioned, it works in a strange way. When I turn one of the monitors off, it changes nothing. Only when I turn the monitor on again, Windows detects it being disconnected and immediately reconnected, changing the config to one screen and then instantly to two screens again. This is kinda annoying because I often want to turn off the secondary screen, when I don't need it, and not be infuriated with programs opening or maximizing on the wrong screen, which Windows thinks is still there, or with the cursor getting lost.

The graphics is 6900XT, both it and the monitors support DP 1.4. So is there a way to make the system actually detect monitor disconnection?

Comment: Does Windows recognize that one monitor has been powered off if you open device manager and perform a search for changed devices?

Comment: @Robert checked it, no, when I refresh the devices, both monitors are still there.